Will deleting specific commits from a branch affect the original branch it was created from?
I have a branch A that was created from another branch B. Some specific commits from branch B are also present in branch A. I’m considering deleting those commits from branch A, but I’m concerned about whether this will also delete them from branch B.

If I delete commits from branch A, will those commits be deleted from branch B as well?
Is there a way to make branch A fully independent from branch B so I can remove commits without affecting the original branch?

For context:

I’ve squashed some commits on branch B.


How are you deleting the commits? It seems like you've misunderstood what a branch is. A branch is not a list of commits, it is a pointer to a single commit.

If you edit only history for branch A, than it will not affect branch B and will have brances inconsistency from first deleted commit

What do you mean by "make branch A fully independent"?  Branches do not have any dependencies on other branches, so all branches are already fully independent.  There is some relationship between a local branch and a remote tracking branch, but merely creating A from B did not create any sort of dependency.

Makes no sense. A branch is just a name for one commit. It is not some sort of extended series of commits. If you want to talk about what commits are "on" a branch, the answer is, all the commits starting at that one commit, running backwards thru the parent chain, all the way back to the root commit of the repo.


No, Branch A is derived form Branch B and when you delete them it won't effect the "Parent Branch".

You can use this code git rebase --onto [newParent] [oldParent] [branchToMove]



rebase - Change the parents of something
--onto - This is the flag that tells git to use this alternate rebase
syntax
newParent - This is the branch that the branch you are rebasing will
have as it's parent
oldParent - This is the branch that the branch you are List iterebasing
currently has as it's parent
branchToMove - This is the branch that you are moving (rebasing)

I hope it helped you.
